# Spree: Return only Orders with Line Items in them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I'm having trouble setting up the controller in a spree app so it only returns orders with line_items in them.

```
<Spree::Order id: 1057, number: "R498797188", item_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c2acf4b8,'0.999E1',18(18)>, total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c2acf1e8,'0.1098E1',18(18)>, state: "payment", adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c2ace770,'0.0',9(18)>, user_id: nil, completed_at: nil, bill_address_id: 1814, ship_address_id: 1815, payment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c2acc358,'0.0',9(18)>, shipping_method_id: nil, shipment_state: nil, payment_state: nil, email: nil, special_instructions: nil, created_at: "2015-09-10 22:31:23", updated_at: "2015-09-10 22:33:03", currency: "USD", last_ip_address: "127.0.0.1", created_by_id: nil, shipment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c4b721e8,'0.199E1',18(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c4b71fb8,'0.0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c4b71e78,'0.0',9(18)>, channel: "spree", included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f90c4b71798,'0.0',9(18)>, item_count: 1, approver_id: nil, approved_at: nil, confirmation_delivered: false, considered_risky: false>
```

There is a record on Spree::Order called `item_count` that needs to be > 0, but I don't know what the syntax needs to be in the controller?

```
@orders = Spree::Order.all.where(:item_count > 0) #this returns the following error: comparison of Symbol with 0 failed
```

This seems simple, but any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *symbol* to check for absolute value, like `where(item_count: 0)`, but not for comparison like that.

Inside `where`, when you are using symbols, you are actually working on a `Hash` object.
`.where(item_count: 0)`= `.where({item_count: 0})`
and to work with a hash, you should have key-value pair like above, not comparison. `{:item_count > 0}` is an invalid hash syntax.

For comparison in your case, use string:

```
@orders = Spree::Order.where('item_count > 0').all
```

Also, you should use [`.all`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all), at the end of relation, if all needed. `all` returns the scope object and is usually meant to fetch all the records matching the query before it.